# Run AWS Lambda for multiple parameters one at a time on schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have a lambda function that accepts a parameter i.e a category_id, pulls some data from an API, and updates the database based on the response.
I have to execute the same lambda function for Multiple Ids after an interval of 1 minute on daily basis.
For example, run lambda for category 1 at 12:00 AM, then run for category 2 at 12:01 AM and so one for 500+ categories.
What could be the best possible solution to achieve this?
This is what I am currently thinking:

- Write Lambda using AWS SAM
- Add Lambda Layer for Shared Dependencies
- Attach Lambda with AWS Cloudwatch Events to run it on schedule
- Add Environment Variable for category_id in lambda
- Update the SAM template to use the same lambda function again and again but only change will be in the Cron expression schedule and Value of Environment Variable category_id

Problems in the Above Solution:

- Number of Lambda functions will increase in the account.
- Each Lambda will be attached with a Cloudwatch Event so its number will also increase
- There is a quota limit of max 300 Cloudwatch Event per account (though we can request support to increase that limit)
- It'll require the use of nested stacks because of the SAM template size limit as well as the number of resources per template which 200 max.
- I'll be able to create only 50 Lambda Functions per nested stack, it means the number of nested stacks will also increase because 1 lambda = 4 resources (Lambda + Role + Rule + Event)

Other solutions (not sure if they can be used):

- Use of Step Functions
- Trigger First Lambda function only using Cron Schedule and Invoke Lambda for the next category using current lambda(only one CloudWatch Event will be required to invoke the function for the first category but time difference will vary i.e next lambda will not execute exactly after one minute).
- Use Only One Lambda and One Cloud Watch Schedule Event, Lambda Function will have a list of all category ids and that function will invoke itself recursively by using one category id at a time and removing the use category id from the list (the only problem is lambda will not execute exactly after one minute for next category_id in the list)

Looking forward to hearing about the best solution.

Comment: Does it call the **same Lambda function** every minute (with a different parameter), or is there a **different Lambda function** that needs to be called each time?

Comment: Why does it need to be called at each minute? What if one execution of the Lambda function takes longer than a minute? Alternatively, if it only takes 30 seconds to run a function, is it okay for the next category to start immediately, rather than having to wait for the next minute? Are there any limitations or bottlenecks in the Lambda functions that prevent them from **running simultaneously** (eg all trying to use the same database)?

Comment: the same lambda with the same implementation logic just different parameters at each automated execution.

Comment: The execution of the One Lambda function takes less than 30 seconds
the reason it needs to be called at each minute is the third party API which does not allow consecutive API calls and blocks the requests. so to delay the next API call it needs to be executed with some delay, obviously, we can't add sleep statements in the same lambda because sleep statements in lambda still cost execution time, and also lambda timout limit will not allow much number of categories.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Will it be good to have 500+ Scheduled Events with different static inputs?

Comment: @RajeshPal I suggest that you create a new question with full information, rather than asking a question via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using a standard Worker pattern:

- Create an **Amazon SQS queue**
- Configure the AWS Lambda function so that it is **triggered to run whenever a message is sent to the SQS queue**
- Trigger a separate process at midnight (eg another Lambda function) that **sends the 500 messages to the SQS queue**, each with a different category ID

This will cause the Amazon SQS functions to execute. If you only want one of the Lambda functions to be running at any time (with no parallel executions), **set the function's Concurrency Limit to 1** so that only one is running at any time. When one function completes, Lambda will automatically grab another message from the queue and start executing. There will be practically no "wasted time" between executions of the function.

Comment: looks like a promising solution, however, the delay is required between batches of one message at a time.
Can we use SQS delay queues to delay the consumption of each message by lambda?
SQS delay queue will add some cost for the wait time or not?

Comment: No, the Delay configuration on an SQS queue does not apply to Lambda triggers. How much of a gap do you require between Lambda executions?

Comment: the required gap should be random automatically if every lambda execution time Is different, however, it can be 20 seconds to 40 seconds.

Comment: Since your other awesome answer added some relevant costs,  could you add that to this answer too?

Comment: That's not easy. If you were to use the base 128MB Lambda function for 500 x 30 seconds, it would be about 3c, plus API costs (quite small). Amazon SQS is designed for millions of messages, so 500 messages hardly costs anything (500 x 3 API calls to create, retrieve and delete). So, from a cost basis, Lambda would appear cheaper than EC2, but it is a more complex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are doing a large amount of processing, an Amazon EC2 instance might be more appropriate.

If the bandwidth requirements are low (eg if it is just making API calls), then a T3a.micro ($0.0094 per Hour) or even T3a.nano instance ($0.0047 per Hour) can be quite cost-effective.

A script running on the instance could process a category, then sleep for 30 seconds, in a big loop. Running 500 categories at one minute each would take about 8 hours. That's under 10c each day!

The instance can then stop or self-terminate when the work is complete. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)